# How to type '#' for all strings selected

Tags: python

Sorry for the dumb question, I'm obviously a beginner and i don't know the command to type '#' at the beginning of all strings selected so i'm currently doing it manually one by one.

Comment: Are you trying to comment out lines that are selected?

Comment: This is a feature that is dependent on your editor. You should be able to figure it out by searching the web for something like "comment out lines keyboard shortcut [editor name]".

Comment: Thank you! forgot to mention i'm using pycharm

Comment: For PyCharm, you can use `CTRL+/` to comment and `CTRL+SHIFT+/` to uncomment sections of code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using pycharm you can do CTRL + /, or going to the menu CODE and select "Comment selected with inline comment" or something like that.

It depends on the IDE you're using boss.

Comment: Thank you very much!